# "To be prepared" - Verb tense question

Tags: verbs

In the sentence below, is the word "prepared" used correctly? I my opinion, it was incorrect, since the sentence is a general statement, therefore the verb "prepare" hasn't been been performed so therefore it should be "prepare" instead of "prepared".

> The more prepared you are going into the exam, the better off you’ll be.

Comment: Most people who prepare do it before the event. Indeed the *pre-* prefix suggests this.Alternatively, compare the correct "you are more prepared" with the incorrect "you are more prepare".

Comment: @Henry I'm not sure what you're saying. So should it be prepare or prepared.

Comment: The past participle is the adjectival form of a verb. "He was more prepared."

Comment: The first clause has present tense -- that's the "are".  The -ed ending of "prepared" is not a past tense, but is the passive participle, or perhaps an adjective-forming suffix.  (The passive participle is traditionally called "past participle", but that is misleading, because it is not a past tense.)

Comment: I think prepared is just a plain-old adjective in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is correct as is.

This is because *prepared* is actually an adjective: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prepared. If you want to get specific, in this scenario it is used as a subject complement; you can rearrange the words "prepared you are" to "you are prepared."

In short, you don't have to worry about tense in this example; though *prepared* ends with *ed*, it is not a conjugated verb. Some other examples of past participles that are used as adjectives are *bored*, *interested*, and *frightened*. However, if you wanted to change the sentence to use *prepare* as a verb, you could change the sentence to "The more you prepare for your exam, the better off you'll be."

Answer (score -1):

We can say "The more you are prepared for exams, the more you will be better off."

Comment: No, you cannot say “the more you will be better off”, although you could get away with “the better off you will be”.